# Pandas inter-column referencing

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data as follows:

```
+--------+------+
| Reason | Keys |
+--------+------+
| x      | a    |
| y      | a    |
| z      | a    |
| y      | b    |
| z      | b    |
| x      | c    |
| w      | d    |
| x      | d    |
| w      | d    |
+--------+------+
```

I want to get the `Reason` corresponding to the first occurrence of each `Key`. Like here, I should get `Reasons` `x,y,x,w` for `Keys` `a,b,c,d` respectively.  After that, I want to compute the percentage of each `Reason`, as in a metric for how many times each `Reason` occurs. Thus `x = 2/4 = 50%.` And `w,y = 25%` each.

For the percentage, I think I can use something like `value_counts(normalize=True) * 100`, based on the previous step. What is a good way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the second step and the first step could be achieved by

```
summary = df.groupby("Keys").first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Reason'])
Out[207]: 
  Reason Keys
0      x    a
1      y    a
2      z    a
6      w    d
```

Comment: Please see edit as to expected output format. I think the table in your answer needs further manipulation.